# In-app "Done" translation?

Tags: translation, software

In our mobile app we have a kind of media gallery where you can select several images to put them into a "social album". On the English translation of the app the term `Done` in the right top corner is used to finalize this kind of selection and leave this screen.

I'm wondering if the German `Erledigt` is the proper equivalent here.

[image: German translation for Done]

Comment: "Fertig" seems appopriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple benutzt "Fertig", zum Beispiel hier:

[image: Abbrechen ... Fertig]

Answer (score 1):

1. *Erledigt* hat für mich eher einen Bezug zu Aufgaben.
2. *Erledigt*/*Done* kommt für mich eher einem Status gleich.

Wenn es aber einen *Abbrechen*-Button gibt, spricht nichts gegen *OK, Fertig, Weiter* oder bspw. *Spiele ab.*
Ich favorisiere eher Begrifflichkeiten, die eine Aktion vermitteln, als einen generischen Text wie *OK.*

Comment: Beachte, dass *erledigt* wie das englische *done* das Partizip eines Verbs ist.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Danke - aber auch der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/erledigt) sowie [Wiktioniary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/erledigt) definieren *erledigt* als Adjektiv, obgleich es auch eine Referenz als Partizip II gibt.

Comment: Ich bestreite ja auch nicht, dass es ein Adjektiv ist. Ich stelle nur fest, dass es grammatikalisch wenig anders als das englische *done* ist, was im Original verwendet wurde.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft sry, falsch verstanden ;) ...